# Python - How to output strings that are in a list, that have a certain number of letters in them

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

Using Python 3.7, I have a list that contains strings of various lengths.  I'm trying to use functions to only return strings that have two letters - my threshold.  I am currently getting a single string output of "a", when I really want "a", "ab", and "ac" to be printed.  I do not know where I am going wrong?  I know that len(xStr) will count the number of letters in a string, but I'm not sure how to use it correctly here.

This is my attempted code:

```
threshold = 2
def listOfWords(list):
    stringList = ["a", "ab", "abc", "ac", "abcd"]
    return stringList

def wordsInListsCounter():
    for elements in listOfWords(list):
        if len(elements) <= threshold:
            strLessThanThreshold = elements
            return strLessThanThreshold
        elif len(elements) == 0:
            emptyString = "There are no words in this list"
            return emptyString
        else:
            error = "There is invalid information"
            return error
print(wordsInListsCounter())
```

Any help would be appreciated!!  I'm a newbie Python user here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> stringList = ["a", "ab", "abc", "ac", "abcd"]
>>> modifiedList = [x for x in stringList if len(x) <= 2]
>>> modifiedList
['a', 'ab', 'ac']
```

I've edited my answer to better match your question, here's what I would add:

```
threshold = 2
myList = ["a", "ab", "abc", "ac", "abcd"]

def wordsInListsCounter(stringList):
    elements = []
    for element in stringList:
        if len(element) <= threshold:
            elements.append(element)
    return elements

elements = wordsInListsCounter(myList)

if len(elements) == 0:
    print("There are no words in this list")

else:
    print(elements)
```

Comment: Thanks.  How can I incorporate your suggestion in the code I currently have?  I want to try and do this string/letter counter thing using functions...

Comment: there are some issues with your initial code: 
1. listOfWords  takes a list argument... that you do not use
2. your for loop works on elements of the list... but then you test if the len(elements)==0 so I think you're mixing element vs full list
that's why I separated the filtering, it's in wordsInListsCounter
the post processing where you check the list length is done once the filtering is done

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where and how to fix it :-)

Comment: yes, I hope what I said in this last comment will help you!

Answer (score 1):

Incorperating @kevh’s answer into your code would look like so:

```
threshold = 2

def listOfWords(list):
    stringList = ["a", "ab", "abc", "ac", "abcd"]
    return stringList

def wordsInListsCounter():
    elements = listOfWords(list)

    if len(elements) != 0:
         strLessThanThreshold = [x for x in elements if len(x) <= threshold]
         return strLessThanThreshold

    elif len(elements) == 0:
        emptyString = "There are no words in this list"
        return emptyString

    else:
        error = "There is invalid information"
        return error

print(wordsInListsCounter())
```

However, if you don’t want to use a list comprehension, you can use the following:

```
threshold = 2
def listOfWords(list):
    stringList = ["a", "ab", "abc", "ac", "abcd"]
    return stringList

def wordsInListsCounter():
    strLessThanThreshold = []
    elements = listOfWords(list)

    for element in elements :
        if len(element) <= threshold:
            strLessThanThreshold.append(element)

    if len(elements) == 0:
        emptyString = "There are no words in this list"
        return emptyString

    return strLessThanThreshold

print(wordsInListsCounter())
```

Comment: Now I can see how this can be used.  Thanks!